# Disambiguating a PHP namespace used by two vendors

Tags: php, namespaces, drupal-7, composer-php, psr-4

I have two composer packages in my app that are creating a namespace collision in a third party module. I'm trying to determine the least disruptive way to disambiguate within the third party module so that I don't have to fork the packages.

First package from Vendor X, located in a directory structure like

`path/to/vendor/VendorX/MailPackageA`:

```
<?php

namespace MailPackageA;

class Mail {
    ...
}
```

My existing third-party module, which lists `VendorX/MailPackageA` as a dependency, located in structure like

`moduleDirectory/MailingModule/mail.inc`:

```
<?php

class ThirdPartyMailMod implements CoreMailSystem {

    $mail_object = new MailPackageA\Mail();
    . . .

}
```

For slightly different mailing functionality used in another module, I had to add a package that uses the same `namespace` identifier (`MailPackageA`), but from a different vendor, "VendorY". Like VendorX/MailPackageA, it's placed in a directory structure like

`path/to/vendor/VendorY/MailPackageA`:

```
<?php

namespace MailPackageA;

class Mail {
    ...
}
```

After adding this, I get errors in MailingModule/mail.inc at `$mail_object = new MailPackageA\Mail();` because of the obvious namespace collision between `MailPackageA\Mail` classes from `VendorY` and `VendorX`.

Routes I've already been down, but failed:

- Modify PSR-4 autoload rules in composer.json for either of the packages to create new namespaces. (I'm getting the sense my framework -- Drupal 7 -- does not respect the composer autoload rules, and simply defaults to stock php 7 namespacing), so I've abandoned that for the moment.
- Try to add a vendor prefix alias to the MailingModule/mail.inc file with `use`.

  ```
  <?php

  use VendorX\MailPackageA; 

  \\ also tried the `use VendorX\MailPackageA as MailPackageA;` pattern to no effect

  class ThirdPartyMailMod implements CoreMailSystem {

      $mail_object = new MailPackageA\Mail();

  }
  ```

  I suspect that my app doesn't know about the vendor directories. Not sure how to force that.

What's the least disruptive way (i.e. minimal forking/patching) to make sure MailingModule only uses the MailPackageA\Mail class from Vendor X?

Comment: Do you `include vendor/autoload.php` anywhere in the project? If Drupal (7 or less) doesn't respect PSR-4, it is no use relying on its autoloader to get the classes from vendor packages.

Comment: If two seperate modules use the same namespace and don't respect the common rules of namespacing, there's nothing you can do but opening bug reports

Answer (score 0):

to overcome this problem use `alias` when you use the `namespace` .
use `as` keyword like this

```
use VendorX\MailPackageA as newPackageName;
```

and if you need to call the class from this namespace you will have it like this

```
$packageName = new newPackageName\Mail();
```

Comment: Thanks @samehanwar. When I try that approach, I get the following error: `Error: Class 'VendorX\MailpackagaA\Mail' not found in ThirdPartyMailMod`

Comment: That won't work if there is no visible difference between a class from the namespace `MailPackageA` located at folder X and another class from the namespace `MailPackageA` located at another folder